# Define resources in C# instead of xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, wpfdatagrid

I would like to access to my staticData using a usercontrol in c#. But in order to do that i think i need to define resources in C# instead of xaml.

Can anyone help me?

Everything in project is working but when i'm trying to access to my table it doesn't return anything because is just defined in xaml.

UserControl:
GroupingZoomedInView.xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="CaiMU_Professor.Grouping.GroupingZoomedInView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CaiMU_Professor.Grouping.Data"
xmlns:telerikGrid="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:PeopleViewModel x:Key="Model"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data,Source={StaticResource Model}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" SelectionUnit="Row">
        <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.GroupDescriptors>
            <telerikGrid:DelegateGroupDescriptor>
                <telerikGrid:DelegateGroupDescriptor.KeyLookup>
                    <local:AlpabeticGroupKeyLookup/>
                </telerikGrid:DelegateGroupDescriptor.KeyLookup>
            </telerikGrid:DelegateGroupDescriptor>
        </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.GroupDescriptors>
        <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Template"/>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="data"/>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="info"/>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="score"/>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="result"/>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="repeats"/>
        </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

GroupingZoomedInView.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class GroupingZoomedInView : UserControl, ISemanticZoomInformation
{
    public String row;

    public GroupingZoomedInView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGrid.SelectionChanged += this.SelectionChanged;
    }

    public void CompleteViewChangeFrom(SemanticZoomLocation source, SemanticZoomLocation destination)
    {
        var list = this.SemanticZoomOwner.ZoomedOutView as GridView;

        if (list != null)
        {
            list.ItemsSource = source.Item;
        }
    }

    public bool IsActiveView {get; set;}
    public bool IsZoomedInView {get; set;}
    public SemanticZoom SemanticZoomOwner{get; set;}

    public void StartViewChangeFrom(SemanticZoomLocation source, SemanticZoomLocation destination)
    {
        source.Item = this.dataGrid.GetDataView().Items.OfType<IDataGroup>().Select(c => c.Key);
    }

    public void StartViewChangeTo(SemanticZoomLocation source, SemanticZoomLocation destination)
    {
        var dataview = this.dataGrid.GetDataView();
        var group = dataview.Items.OfType<IDataGroup>().Where(c => c.Key.Equals(source.Item)).FirstOrDefault();

        var lastGroup = dataview.Items.Last() as IDataGroup;
        if (group != null && lastGroup != null)
        {
            this.dataGrid.ScrollItemIntoView(lastGroup.ChildItems[lastGroup.ChildItems.Count - 1], () =>
            {
                this.dataGrid.ScrollItemIntoView(group.ChildItems[0]);
            });
        }
    }

    private void SelectionChanged(object sender, DataGridSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Templates temp = this.dataGrid.SelectedItem as Templates;
        aux = this.dataGrid.SelectedItem;
    }
 }
```

My Static data

```
public class PeopleViewModel
{
    private static List<Templates> staticData;

    static PeopleViewModel()
    {
        Load();
    }

    public IList<Templates> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return staticData;
        }
    }

    private static void Load()
    {
        XMLStuff xml = new XMLStuff();
        List<Templates> tempList = xml.getControlOutput();
        staticData = new List<Templates>();

        foreach (Templates temp in tempList)
            staticData.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`var model = this.Resources["Model] as PeopleViewModel;`

Comment: It gives me the following error:
"An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Comment: @Kelianosevis that must be a WinRT issue. Im used to work with WPF not WinRT (although it should be the same), so I couldn't tell. Have you tried debugging and checking the resource is actually there?

Comment: With some debugging i found that my resource is not actually there.. But my table which supposedly was correct shows me the correct results.. The debuuger tells me there are no resources.. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to run this code after the UI has Loaded (I.E in the `Loaded` event), not in the constructor or any other moment prior to the Loaded event.

Comment: Also, you have declared the resource in the `Grid`. You should declare it in the root of your XAML (I.E the `UserControl`.